# resued item used on scroll in list view?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a list view in which i have some buttons.On click of each button i am changing it's current colour & set colour of others button as default colour.So when i press button Clean on first position then it's colour change to green & other button colour set to grey.I have 5 rows visible at one time.When i scroll down then clean button on 7th row also gets green.I don't know why.I thought it was list view recycle view issue but according to that 6th row button colour should be changed.Please help me why this is happening i have tried every possible thing i have used **View Holder Pattern** but that is also not working.

**Get View Method**

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {

        select_postion=position;
        Log.i("error","select--"+select_postion);
        note_pos = position;
        // View rowView = convertView;
         if (rowView == null) 
         {
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null, true);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.componentName = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.location_list_row);
                holder.clean = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
                holder.dirty = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
                holder.dc = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
                holder.na = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn4);
                holder.camra = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn5);
                holder.camra.setTag(position);
                holder.notes = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn6);
                holder.count_text = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.circle_count);
                holder.red_circle = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img_red);
                holder.position=position;
                holder.clean.setTag(holder);
                holder.camra.setTag(holder);
                holder.na.setTag(holder);
                holder.dc.setTag(holder);
                holder.notes.setTag(holder);
                holder.dirty.setTag(holder);
                rowView.setTag(holder);
         }
         else 
         {      
             // rowView=convertView;
                holder=(ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();
         }

                LocationInspectionBean location_obj = values.get(position);
                if (values.get(position).getImages() != null)
                {
                    imgpath = values.get(position).getImages();
                    imgpath1 = imgpath.split(",");
                    count = imgpath1.length;
                    holder.red_circle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.count_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.count_text.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                }
                holder.componentName.setText(location_obj.getComp_name());

                if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                {
                    holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C6614"));
                    Log.i("SYNC", "Status is 1");
                }

                else if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("3"))
                {
                    holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FC4E3B"));
                    Log.i("SYNC", "Status is 3");
                }
                else if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
                    holder.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0D6CC3"));
                    Log.i("SYNC", "Status is 4");
                }
                else if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                    holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E87403"));
                    Log.i("SYNC", "Status is 2");

                }
                if (location_obj.getNotes().isEmpty()) {
                    holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));

                }
                else if (location_obj.getNotes().isEmpty()) {
                    holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));

                }

                holder.clean.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        //  Log.i("SYNC", "camera"+String.valueOf(index));

                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C6614"));
                        ViewHolder h = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                        index=  h.position;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        h.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                        h.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                        h.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
                        Status = "1";
                    //  index = (Integer)v.getTag();
                        Log.i("SYNC", String.valueOf(index));
                        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format(new Date());

                        db.updateInspectionDetails(inspection_id, user_id,
                                location_inspection_array.get(position)
                                        .getComponentid(), subclient_id, client_id,
                                Status, images_path_string, timeStamp);

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You need to store the state of button i.e, which button is `green color` on which row, which button's are `gray color`.

Comment: How can i do that.Few have suggessted to put button in if block & some of them suggested to put in outside the if block so what is the right way????

Comment: According to location status you are changing the `color` am I right?

Comment: in two way i am chnaging color by pressing the button & also by mathcing the value from database.Can you please help me i am stuck badly

Comment: According to `location_obj.getInspectionstatus()` this right?

Comment: In side `onTouch()` method you need to handle that.

Comment: How to handle that ?? that is what i nedd to understand i have tried so many things but nothing seems to work for me.I need help on that

Comment: Actually, what is that other color's you are setting?

Comment: on click of button A  i am setting it's color as green & all other button color as grey ,for button B i am setting color Blue & all other button color as grey,For button C i am setting color as Orange & all other button color as grey.

Comment: Then, why you are not setting the colors of other buttons inside if conditions?

Comment: I updated the code check

Comment: OK, let me check and tell.

Comment: I have posted the answer, please check, and let me know.

Comment: @deepakkumar What is the status, whether the solution is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Everytime getView(), you should set color to the button because it may be old reused buttons. So the problem in your code is that you've set it green but no grey. To solve the problem, you just need change the code:

```
            if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            {
                holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C6614"));
                Log.i("SYNC", "Status is 1");
            }
```

to :

```
            if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            {
                holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C6614"));
                Log.i("SYNC", "Status is 1");
            }
            else
            {
                holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor({COLOR_GREY}));
                Log.i("SYNC", "Status is not 1");
            }
```

{COLOR_GREY} is string of your custom grey color.

> 2. But there is another problem: data is not updated. So you need to change the onTouch() in your onTouchListener, before the last line:

```
            return false;
```

Add a line to update data, like:

```
            values.get(position).setInspectionstatus("1");
            return false;
```

It runs well. The problem happened because you've updated data in db but havn't updated those in your Java Bean "values".

Comment: @deepakkumar Have you seen log info: "Status is not 1"?

Comment: @deepakkumar You havn't update your data, so it must go wrong. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

please modify your `getView()` method to below

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {
    select_postion = position;
    Log.i("error", "select--" + select_postion);
    note_pos = position;
    // View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.componentName = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.location_list_row);
        holder.clean = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        holder.dirty = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        holder.dc = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        holder.na = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        holder.camra = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        holder.camra.setTag(position);
        holder.notes = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        holder.count_text = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.circle_count);
        holder.red_circle = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img_red);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // rowView=convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    holder.position = position;
    holder.clean.setTag(holder);
    holder.camra.setTag(holder);
    holder.na.setTag(holder);
    holder.dc.setTag(holder);
    holder.notes.setTag(holder);
    holder.dirty.setTag(holder);

    LocationInspectionBean location_obj = values.get(position);
    if (values.get(position).getImages() != null) {
        imgpath = values.get(position).getImages();
        imgpath1 = imgpath.split(",");
        count = imgpath1.length;
        holder.red_circle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.count_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.count_text.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }
    holder.componentName.setText(location_obj.getComp_name());

    holder.clean.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //  Log.i("SYNC", "camera"+String.valueOf(index));

            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C6614"));
            ViewHolder h = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            index = h.position;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            h.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
            h.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
            h.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
            Status = "1";
            //  index = (Integer)v.getTag();
            Log.i("onTouch", String.valueOf(index));
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format(new Date());

            values.get(index).setInspectionstatus("1");

            return false;
        }
    });

    if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
        holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C6614"));
        holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        holder.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        Log.i("SYNC", "Status is 1");
    } else if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
        holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FC4E3B"));
        holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        holder.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        Log.i("SYNC", "Status is 3");
    } else if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
        holder.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0D6CC3"));
        holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        Log.i("SYNC", "Status is 4");
    } else if (location_obj.getInspectionstatus().equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
        holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E87403"));
        holder.clean.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        holder.na.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));
        Log.i("SYNC", "Status is 2");
    }
    if (location_obj.getNotes().isEmpty()) {
        holder.dirty.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));

    } else if (location_obj.getNotes().isEmpty()) {
        holder.dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8787"));

    }
    return rowView;
}
```

Let me know for further issues.